# NativeScript ListView itemTap won't empty items

Tags: javascript, android, ios, xml, nativescript

As part of a NativeScript iOS/Android app I'm building, I need to:
1. Search a list of items
2. Select one of the search results
3. As a result of selecting one, clear the search results

But it's not working. What's odd is that the same clearItems function works when attached to the SearchBar being cleared, it just doesn't work when tapping on an item in the ListView.

Here's the relevant code:

XML

```
<Page>
    <AbsoluteLayout loaded="layoutLoaded">
        <SearchBar hint="Search for your opponent" id="search" submit="performSearch" />
        <ListView id="itemList" items="{{ itemList }}" visibility="{{ listVisible ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}">
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <WrapLayout>
                    <Image cssClass="itemImage" src="{{ image }}" />
                    <Label cssClass="itemLabel" text="{{ niceName }}" />
                </WrapLayout>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</Page>
```

JavaScript

```
function clearItems(thisLayout){
    thisLayout.bindingContext.itemList = [];
    thisLayout.bindingContext.listVisible = false;
}

exports.layoutLoaded = function(args){

    var thisLayout = args.object

    thisLayout.bindingContext = {
        itemList: [],
        listVisible: false
    };

    var searchBar = view.getViewById(thisLayout, 'search');

    searchBar.on(searchBarModule.SearchBar.clearEvent, function(args) {
        clearItems(args.object.parent);
    });

    var itemListWrap = view.getViewById(thisLayout, 'itemList');

    itemListWrap.on('itemTap', function(args){
        var page = args.object.parent;
        clearItems(page);
    });

}
```

Many thanks for anyone who can help. I assume there's something more complicated about a list item clearing it's own parent list.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question but two things. First, bind the bindingContext to an observable object/array (see https://docs.nativescript.org/bindings.html and https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/data/observable-array/HOW-TO.html ). Seconds, Clear the list by emptying the array rather than redefine it, e.g.: while(itemList.length > 0) { itemList.pop(); }. Here's a video explaining how to work with observable objects/arrays: https://youtu.be/MhwBpVRfljU?t=1402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emil's advice ultimately solved it for me.

I changed to using an observable object, which meant when tapping on a list item, I could successfully empty the array:

```
function clearItems(viewModel){
    while(viewModel.itemList.length > 0){
        viewModel.itemList.pop();
    }
    viewModel.set('listVisible', false);
}

var viewModel = new observableModule.Observable({
    listVisible: false,
    itemList: new observableArrayModule.ObservableArray([])
});

exports.layoutLoaded = function(args){

    var thisLayout = args.object

    thisLayout.bindingContext = viewModel;

    var searchBar = view.getViewById(thisLayout, 'search');

    searchBar.on(searchBarModule.SearchBar.clearEvent, function(args) {
        clearItems(viewModel);
    });

    var itemListWrap = view.getViewById(thisLayout, 'itemList');

    itemListWrap.on('itemTap', function(args){
        clearItems(viewModel);
    });

}
```